# Chrome Sync Error needs Passphrase

Tags: google-chrome, sync

[image: Update Sync Passphrase] For the past week or so, there's a small orange error symbol in the top right corner when I open Chrome. It says to "Update sync passphrase". I don't remember ever having to enter a passphrase for this. It says I can reset it via the Google Dashboard but won't that delete passwords, autofill among other things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've changed your Google Account password, then the sync passphrase will be your Google Account password *prior* to the one you changed to.

So if you changed your Google Account from hunter2 to hunter3, then the sync passphrase will be hunter2

Comment: @ChristopherChipps you're welcome!

Comment: @Sathya I have the exact same problem, I tried my last password and didn't work. There is another workaround, or a support email that I can ask for help. If you or any knows anything will be a great thing for me.

Comment: @MichelAyres did you change your password before that? I'm unaware of any support email for Chrome

Comment: If there was a support, I could exclude all data and ask for a previous backup. I changed it a lot, and tried all that I could remember, none was the right one.